# MIDI instrument not working for javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel

Tags: java, midi, javasound, synthesizer

I am currently working on an application to play some MIDI with different instruments. I am using the javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel for this and it works fine with guitar (index 25) and bass (index 32). Now I want to add a Mandolin channel; according to synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank().getInstruments(), this is index 215. But with the code below, the program of the Mandolin channel gets set to 25 (same as guitar channel). According to the documentation, only values between 0 and 127 are allowed at the programChange() method...
Any ideas how I can configure my channel to work with Mandolin as instrument?

```
        Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synthesizer.open();

        final Instrument[] instruments = synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank().getInstruments();

        MidiChannel guitarChannel = synthesizer.getChannels()[0];
        guitarChannel.programChange(instruments[25].getPatch().getProgram());

        MidiChannel bassChannel = synthesizer.getChannels()[1];
        bassChannel.programChange(instruments[32].getPatch().getProgram());

        MidiChannel mandolinChannel = synthesizer.getChannels()[2];
        mandolinChannel.programChange(instruments[215].getPatch().getProgram());

        mandolinChannel.noteOn(note, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *theory* you'll need to use the `.getBank()` method of the patch and supply both the bank number and the program number to `.programChange()`.

In practise, when I try to replicate your issue myself, it seems that the default `com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer` doesn't appear to support bank changes at all.

Comment: The hint with the bank was just what I needed. In the Debug view I could see, that instruments[215] has bank number 2048. So I added this number to the programChange method call and it worked: mandolinChannel.programChange(2048, instruments[215].getPatch().getProgram());

Comment: If the code is intended to run on other systems then do use `getBank()` to find that number - there's no guarantee whatsoever that it'll always be 2048.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 128 total instrument programs in General MIDI, so you will not be able to use instrument 215, which probably doesn't exist.

There are a list of all the available midi instruments on Wikipedia, you might be able to find something quite close to what your looking for there.

Comment: *"There are a list of all the available midi instruments on Wikipedia"* The Java Sound API can provide its own [list of instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7810530/418556).